# Json.NET deserialization and property setter side-effects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

A question arose when I came across a property setter which had side-effects (it was bad design against [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

The following question is a bit theoretical, and the problem should ideally be fixed by removing the side-effects from the property setters.

But *if* modifying the DTO class is not an option, is there any mechanism to prevent JSON deserialization from causing side-effects when using Json.NET?

**Problem scenario:**

Shown below are `Myclass` and two JSON snippets.

When I call `JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyClass>(json)`, I get different results depending on the order of the JSON properties.

**Data transfer class:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _evilField1;
    public string EvilField1
    {
        get
        {
            return _evilField1;
        }
        set
        {
            _evilField1 = value;
            Info = "EvilField1.Set messed Info";
        }
    }

    private string _evilField2;
    public string EvilField2
    {
        get
        {
            return _evilField2;
        }
        set
        {
            _evilField2 = value;
            Info = "EvilField2.Set messed Info";
        }
    }

    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

**Input data**

```
{
  "EvilField1": "Foo",
  "EvilField2": "Foo",
  "Info": "Initial value"
}

{
  "EvilField1": "Foo",
  "Info": "Initial value",
  "EvilField2": "Foo"
}
```

**Deserialized data**

The first JSON does not trigger the side-effect, but the second JSON brings nasty output:

```
{
  "EvilField1": "Foo",
  "Info": "Initial value",
  "EvilField2": "Foo"
}

{
  "EvilField1": "Foo",
  "EvilField2": "Foo",
  "Info": "EvilField2.Set messed Info"
}
```

Comment: Don't add behaviour to DTOs... recipe for sadness... different serialisers behave in different ways, no guarantees of correct behaviour.

Comment: Why not sure Subclass the DTO and add a constructor, whatever serialiser lib you use, force it to use your constructor, do all the correct init in there?

Comment: @tigerswithguitars I know, dto/property setter side effects is evil and fix should be removing those :)  hmm subclass + custom ctor sounds interesting way for workaround..

Comment: You can deserialize json file as another type or you can reoder lines in json file.

Comment: This isn't so much an issue with JSON.NET as it is with the fact this isn't a true DTO. Best thing to do is create a DTO, then map the properties manually in the "correct" order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for the problematic class.  This will allow you to populate it in whatever way you need to in order to work around the unwanted side effects.

```
public class MyClassConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyClass);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;

        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Populate the "Info" field last so it will not be overwritten
        return new MyClass
        {
            EvilField1 = (string)obj["EvilField1"],
            EvilField2 = (string)obj["EvilField2"],
            Info = (string)obj["Info"]
        };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter you can either add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute the problematic class...

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyClassConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    ...
}
```

... or you can pass an instance of the converter to the `DerserializeObject()` method via settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new MyClassConverter());

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json, settings);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ob4dPA

Comment: Nice! Tested this and works smoothly..This way it is possible to leave "dto" as is (in case it comes from external assembly etc...) and workaround the problem..